# How to use Callbacks in React-native?

Tags: objective-c, react-native, callback, react-native-ios

I was trying to follow Facebook's documentation, but unfortunately they don't explain how to use, and where to use.
I want to make a sample example for callbacks to work

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html

I did as in the documentation, currently facing a problem saying : "this.setState is not a function. (In this.setState({events: events}), this.setState is undefined".

Would be grateful if someone could help me out here.

`Edit:`

I managed to solve the this.setState problem, but my main question now is how I make these callbacks work?

This is the code in Objective-C under file `CalendarManager`

```
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(findEvents:(RCTResponseSenderBlock)callback) {
  NSArray *events;
  events = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:  @"foo", @"bar", nil];
  callback(@[[NSNull null], events]);
}
```

The code in js, is under file `index.ios.js`

```
var CalendarManager = NativeModules.CalendarManager;
CalendarManager.addEvent('Birthday Party', '4 Privet Drive, Surrey');
CalendarManager.findEvents((error, events) => {
  if (error) {
    console.error(error);
  } else {
    console.log('Call back works!');
  }
});
```

`Edit 2`

I managed to make the callbacks work from objective-c to js, now how do I make a callback from js to objective-c?

Comment: Please share code where you are getting error or update question. Error and topic name not match with each other.

Comment: You're right, I'll re-edit my question

Comment: What do you mean by a 'callback from js to objective-c'?

Comment: @marinarroyo I mean that I want to pass a string for example, from js to objective-c method.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

An Objective-C method

```
RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(getString:(NSString *)str) {
  NSLog(@"Your String", str) 
}
```

and in JS, you call it in your everywhere you want like:

```js
yourNativeModule.getString("yourstring")
```